# How to mock Hashmap.get() using Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have this code

```
 private final Map<String, ReEncryption> reEncryptionInstances =
      new HashMap<>();


public ReEncryption getReEncryptionLibInstance ()
    throws ReEncryptionException
{
    final String schemaName = getSchemaName();
    final ReEncryption reEncryption = reEncryptionInstances.get(schemaName);
    if (reEncryption != null) {
        return reEncryption;
    }
    createReEncryptionLibInstance();
    if(reEncryptionInstances.get(schemaName) == null) {
        throw new ReEncryptionException(ERROR_LIBRARY_NOT_INITIALIZED);
    }
    return reEncryptionInstances.get(schemaName);

}
```

ReEncryptionInstances is a Hashmap and i want to set reEncryptionInstances.get(schemaName) == null to test my if block. How can i do that in my test class?

Comment: Why can't you just clear/remove from the real map in your test? You shouldn't mock when you can use a real instance of something.

Comment: When writing unittest it is not useful to mock any *Collection* types. Just use any suitable implementation provided by the JVM.

Comment: how can i clear the map in java class from my test class??

Answer (score 0):

I can see two approaches here:

1. Wrap that `reEncryptionInstances` into a different class
2. Partially mock the class under test, so the `createReEncryptionLibInstance` does not do anything.

Option #1 would look like this:

```
public class YourClassUnderTest {

    private final EncryptionInstances reEncryptionInstances;

    public YourClassUnderTest(EncryptionInstances reEncryptionInstances) {
        // You can do it in a setter too
        // You can inject a Map too
        this.reEncryptionInstances = reEncryptionInstances;
    }

    // ...

}

//...

/** 
 * You can also mock the EncryptionInstances class.
 */
public class TestEncryptionInstances extends EncryptionInstances {
    public ReEncryption getEncryption(String schemaName) {
        return null;
    }
    //...
}
```

Option #2 is generally a bad practice. So I am just pointing to [Mockito.spy()](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) and partial mocking.